# python in built hash and hashlib.md5() different results?

Tags: python, image, hash

I need to find duplicate images between datasets. SO I try to hash them into buckets. Using the inbuilt hash function I get around 1000 duplicates, but using hashlib.md5() I get no duplicates at all?
why is that?
the dataset I am using is the noMNIST, the 2 datasets were taken from there, one is much bigger than the other ie size 200000 and 10000

here is my code :

```
# check for duplicates in the 2 dataset images

import hashlib
def checkDuplicates(data1, data2):
    data1.flags.writeable = False
    data2.flags.writeable = False
    duplicates = 0
    table = {}
    for i in range(0,len(data1),1):
        h = hashlib.md5(data1[i,:,:].data)
        table[h] = i
    for id,image in enumerate(data2):
        h = hashlib.md5(image.data)
        if (h in table) and (data1[table[h],:,:].data == image.data):
            duplicates += 1
    print (duplicates)
    return duplicates
```

If I replace this hashlib.md5() with just the hash() function it gives me 1000-1200 duplicates!!! Why such a difference?

Comment: Because an object hash has nothing to do with the calculated (md5) hash value of some data.

Comment: MD5 produces 128 bit hashes, the Python built-in hash produces 32 bit hashes (on 32 bit Python). I'll let you do the probability calculation... Also see  [cryptographic hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function)